# Iterating through two tables/Entities using lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

using lambda expression I am getting a list of records based on date value using Entity Framework, which is working fine.

```
DateTime expDate=DateTime.Now(+2);
abcEntities se = new abcEntities();
 var c = se.t_valid_id.ToList().Where(x => x.expiration <= expDate && x.expiration >= DateTime.Now);
```

What next I am trying to do is take this list `c` and than take each record comparing `c.id` compare with id in another entity(table) called `t_validate`, whichever values match I need to save that record in a list.
I have no idea how to go about it, any help???

```
var newlist=se.t_validate.ToListe().Where.........
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now(+2)` does not look correct. Also why the `ToList()` after `t_valid_id` and `t_validate`?

Answer (score 1):

It is not fully clear with your sample, but probably this will help you

```
var newlist = .... .Where(x => c.Any(a => a.id == x.id));
```